# My root partition is full in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, root, partition

My root partition is showing full.

I checked all the files which needs to be delete.

Now there are no big files to delete. What is the solution?

Comment: PS: I have Full virtualize cluster. only one physical server.

Comment: If no big files are left but it's still full, delete small files. Seriously though, try to provide more details so that people can understand the specifics of your issue

Comment: What is the output of ''df'' command? What is the size of root? How much dfs and non-dfs memory is used? Provide full details. Otherwise,  you may be receiving downvotes

Comment: Just because files don't exist doesn't mean that **open file handles** aren't left behind